# The page isn't redirecting properly when install magento 1.6

Tags: magento, installation

When I install magento 1.6, it shows below errors, thanks for giving some advise:

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error message when installing the Enterprise training environment.  I just needed to delete app/etc/local.xml to clear out the default settings and allow the install process to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I needed to delete database and create a new one. Even if the previous one was empty without any table. Still don't know why, but I found this solution from somebody who had the same problem.